# SQLite inconsistent performance

Tags: performance, qt, sqlite

I have a hand written ORM built on top of the Qt object system. I'm testing it with SQLite back end, and I'm seeing weird performance issues. There are about 10k objects stored in the database. The objects are loaded one by one with separate queries.

One of the queries exhibits changes in execution time: from 1 msec to 10 depending on the primary key ID. This time also includes some operations done by the Qt Sql module.

The query is very simple and looks like this (the id=100 differs between the queries):

```
SELECT * FROM t1, t2 WHERE t1.id = 100 AND t2.id = 100
```

What might cause the same query to perform 10 times worse depending on the row id?

Comment: What do you mean by "Qt object system"? Does that involve QObject instances?

Comment: Yes, I use Qt meta object system in order to lookup the object properties, build the table schemas etc.

Comment: Is which ids are slow, which are faster consistent across test runs?  E.g. if id=100 is slow on a given run, is it slow every on every other run as well?

Comment: No, it is not consistent at all - more like random, but still in batches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that you are timing operations in *milliseconds* the behaviour that you are observing makes quite a bit of sense. Benchmarking *single* query runs with this kind of time granularity normally makes no sense, unless you are only interested in latency, rather than throughput.

With your particular query, for example, you would see a significant difference depending on whether there are mathing rows in `t1`, since that would determine whether SQLite should bother looking at `t2` at all.

Even running *exactly* the same query will produce different results depending on the OS filesystem cache, the process scheduler, the SQLite cache, the position of the hard disk plates and heads and various other factors.

Two be more specific, there are two possibilities:

#### A. `t1.id` and `t2.id` are indexed

This is the most probable case - I'd expect a table column aptly named `id` to be indexed.

Most SQL engines, including SQLite, use some variation of a [B-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) for each index. On SQLite each tree node is a single page in the DB file. With your particular query, SQLite will have to go through:

- Some pages of the `t1.id` index
- Some pages of the `t2.id` index
- The DB pages where the matching rows from both tables are contained.

Depending on your hardware and how the pages are located on the physical medium (e.g. your hard drive), loading a page can easily add a latency of several milliseconds. This is especially visible on large or freshly-loaded databases where the pages are neither in the OS filesystem cache nor in the SQLite3 cache.

In addition, unless your DB is *really* small, it usually won't fit in the SQLite3 cache and cache hits and misses alone can account for rather severe variations in the time a single query needs to complete: an SQLite cache miss forces a read from the filesystem, which can easily cause the DB process to be rescheduled by the OS in favour of another process.

#### B. `t1.id` and `t2.id` are *not* indexed

This is probably easier to visualise: with no indexes, SQLite has to scan the whole table. Assuming that you have a limit in your `SELECT` statement (you do not have one in your example), whether a matching entry will be found immediately or after going through the whole table is up to luck, hence the severe variation in query completion times.